# MongodbCursor , how to iterate through Huge collection?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDb Database which has inside a collection very huge(more than 2 million of documents). I want to iterate it with a cursor. Also during the iteration I have to perform some operations with the current document.

```
var pending_push_cursor = collection.FindAllAs<PendingPush>();
foreach (PendingPush p_push in pending_push_cursor)
{
    operation_with(p_push)
}
```

The major problem is that the operation enqueues the elements, and it is desirable the iteration pause(for a few seconds) in some moments to let the operation process some elements before adding new ones.

Is there a way i can iterate the cursor in some way I can pause it , and resume later?
The MongodbCursor saves the last item accessed? I only know the foreach iteration, but is there some iteration like  this?

```
while(pending_push_cursor.isLast()){
    PendingPush p_push= pending_push_cursor.getNext()
    operation_with(p_push)
 }
```

If something similat exists i can save the last item queried.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: c# and Visual Studio 2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem in using a while loop with the cursor's enumerator (that's pretty much what foreach does anyway, so you can keep using that).

You should keep in mind that the cursor has a timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity which you may reach depending on your particular case. If so you can disable the timeout for that specific cursor.

Here's a simple example:

```
cursor.SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
using (var enumerator = cursor.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var item = enumerator.Current;
        // logic

        if (shouldPause)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A big problem is that i am using MVC ASP.NET so it is right to use a thread.sleep?

Comment: I want to pause the cursor until a  "callback" action is called , or something similar but i don´t know how

Comment: @xabier it was just an example. You can use `await Task.Delay(1000)` without blocking a thread, or wait on some `AutoResetEvent`, it doesn't matter. What's important is that as long as you don't call `MoveNext` the enumerator stays at the same place. Just don't forget to dispose of it at the end.